# How can I delete all existing Pushpins from Bing Maps?

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls, bing-maps, pushpin

Using a different version/flavor of Bing Maps several years ago, I asked this same question and ultimately self-posted the answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940692/how-can-i-clear-all-the-pushpins-from-my-bing-map-and-still-be-able-to-add-more).

But that doesn't work with my Winforms app using the WPF control. With this code:

```
var mapLayerChildren = from c in DataLayer.Children select c;
var kinderGarten = mapLayerChildren.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < kinderGarten.Count(); i++)
{
    if (kinderGarten[i] is Pushpin)
    {
        DataLayer.Children.Remove(kinderGarten[i]);
    }
}
```

...*DataLayer* is not recognized.

And when I try to replace "DataLayer" with "userControl11.myMap.Children" I get this:

[image]

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends to how you have added the pushpins. You need to remove them from the same `Children` collection to which you have added them.

Assuming you have added your pushpins directly to the `Children` collection of the map, then you can find all the pushpins and remove them like this:

```
var map = this.userControl11.myMap;
map.Children.OfType<Pushpin>().ToList().ForEach(pin => {
    map.Children.Remove(pin);           
});
```

Or to remove all children of the map, including pushpin, shape, layer, and etc. you can use:

```
var map = this.userControl11.myMap;
map.Children.Clear();
```